# How to select parent child till end using root parent id in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below the table :
I need to get without `recursion`, but use any other `join` and `union`.

```
Id  ParentId
1   0
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   4
6   5
7   6
8   7
9   8
N   N
```

Without `recursion` use any other `join` queries

Comment: Can i know why you are not using recursion

Comment: And what have you tried? For example I choose `ParentId = 2` what should I get in output?

Comment: I need if possible to other way...i am tried, But not get the solution.

Comment: show what you have tried then, what it produced, then at least we can see that you have tried

Comment: Id  ParentId

3   2
4   2
5   4
6   5
7   6
8   7
9   8
N   N       this is the output     @ gofr1

Comment: SELeCT  * from (  select * from  (select * from table t1 WHERE ParentId IN( select Id from table t1 WHERE t1.ParentId = '2' )) table Join table vv  On   table.Id=vv.Id

Comment: If your `N` at the end indicates, that there is a non-known number of hierarchically structured rows, you'll need some kind of recursion. You might have a look here [Using the hierarchyid Data Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677213.aspx)

Comment: ok..i need atleast 9 th level...if possible..

Comment: if any other option, using union , Joins and Union all, I need anwser...

Comment: May be am using join or union , How many level am getting,  Output Like Level 3 only???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Nvalue INT = 10

SELECT NUMBER AS ID,NUMBER-1 AS ParentID FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT NUMBER FROM master..spt_values WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND @Nvalue
)T
```